# Agent exiting network port missaligned with paired network port

Tags: anylogic

I have an AGV (transporter) agent originally located in the main area, responsible for entering another agent called BeltAndRack where pallets are stored, retrieving them, and returning to main. The model looks like this (the network ports in the main and BeltAndRack agents overlap):

[image: Main]

[image: BeltAndRack agent]

When this agent attempts to return from the BeltAndRack agent, I encounter the following error message:

[image: Error message on simulation console]

[image: Graphical representation of error]

So far, I've noticed that moving the BeltAndRack agent within the main area causes the AGV's path target to adjust accordingly. The same adjustment occurs when I reposition the agent's representation within the agent editor. I've also attempted to have the pallet move independently to a node in the main area and then be picked up by an AGV. However, this resulted in the pallet being transported misaligned with the transporter.

Regarding the control logic, here is the path of a pallet after being retrieved, first within the BeltAndRack agent and then in the main area. Please note that "exit5" is connected to "enter1":

[image: Retreived pallet path inside BeltAndRack]

[image: Retreived pallet path in main]

[image: moveByTransporter1 Properties]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!